# Combining multiple observations into one column in R

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse

I'm working with a Covid19 dataset in which each row contains Covid data (tests, positives, negatives, deaths, etc...) for a particular day in a particular country. This means there are multiple rows for each day since every country's data gets its own row. I'm trying to generalize the data to only include one row per day per *continent*. Is there a simple way to sum all columns where the date is the same?

For example, I'd want to go from a table like this...

| Date | Continent | Country | Positives |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-05 | Europe | United Kingdom | 10 |
| 2020-02-05 | Europe | Poland | 5 |
| 2020-02-05 | Europe | Sweden | 0 |
| 2020-02-06 | Europe | United Kingdom | 12 |
| 2020-02-06 | Europe | Poland | 7 |
| 2020-02-06 | Europe | Sweden | 1 |

to one like this...

| Date | Continent | Positives |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-05 | Europe | 15 |
| 2020-02-06 | Europe | 20 |

The closest I've gotten is

```
covid19EU <- covid19 %>% filter(Continent_Name == "Europe") %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise_all(max)
```

but this returns the highest value instead of summing the value over all observations for the same date, ie

| Date | Continent | Country | Positives |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-05 | Europe | United Kingdom | 10 |
| 2020-02-06 | Europe | United Kingdom | 12 |

Comment: `covid19 %>% count(Date, Continent, wt = Positives, name = "Positives")`

Comment: (I think you have a typo in your example data where Date is going back to 2020-02-05 in the last two rows.)

Comment: When you say "sum all columns" are you saying that your real data has more columns of numeric data to sum, besides Positives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
covid19 %>%
  group_by(Date, Continent) %>%
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

Result

```
  Date       Continent Positives Something_else
  <chr>      <chr>         <int>          <int>
1 2020-02-05 Europe           15              6
2 2020-02-06 Europe           20             15
```

If there's only one column of data to sum, you can use the `count(wt = ...)` shortcut:

```
covid19 %>% 
  count(Date, Continent, wt = Positives, name = "Positives")

#        Date Continent Positives
#1 2020-02-05    Europe        15
#2 2020-02-06    Europe        20
```

---

Example data with another column of numeric data to sum (possibly implied by OP question "Is there a simple way to sum all columns where the date is the same?")

```
covid19 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("2020-02-05","2020-02-05", "2020-02-05",
                       "2020-02-06","2020-02-06","2020-02-06"), 
                      # NOTE UPDATED DATES VS OP
         Continent = c("Europe","Europe","Europe",
                       "Europe","Europe","Europe"),
           Country = c("United Kingdom","Poland",
                       "Sweden","United Kingdom","Poland","Sweden"),
         Positives = c(10L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 7L, 1L),
         Something_else = 1:6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R:

```
aggregate(Positives~Date+Continent,covid19, sum)

        Date Continent Positives
1 2020-02-05    Europe        15
2 2020-02-06    Europe        20
```